# Does the Thomas algorithm work for complex entries

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have tried implementing the [Thomas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#cite_note-Datta2010-2) for a coefficient matrix that has complex entries. It is not behaving as expected. I am wondering if this method is valid for matrices with complex entries, but I can't seem to find a clear answer on this. Thanks.

To address the question from (@Severin Paddadeux). I am solving the equation `Ax=b`, where `A` is neither Hermitian, nor positive definite, e.g.

```
scipy.linalg.ishermitian(A) = False
np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(A) > 0) = False
```

That being said, the above equation is used to solve one time-step in a differential equation with perfectly-matched layers. If I remove the PMLs than the above equation is Hermitian, i.e.

```
scipy.linalg.ishermitian(A) = True
np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(A) > 0) = False
```

Comment: It should work, though I would vary of the stability of the solution. You could always try to compare with LAPACK. Is your matrix Hermitian and positive?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. See my edited question. The matrix is neither Hermitian, nor positive definite (it seems there are a few different definitions of "positive" matrix, I wasn't quite sure which one you meant)

Comment: Mmm... What is bothering me is np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(A) > 0) = False. E.g., LAPACK uses something like [this](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d7a/group__complex_p_tcomputational_gadecb0ce69b03e2b960effe0754e322d4.html#gadecb0ce69b03e2b960effe0754e322d4) factorization, and clearly then diagonal part goes to denominator. So if there is 0 in the diagonals, all bets are off. I would suggest writing small program in C/Fortran to solve your particular matrix and see how it works

Comment: I mean solving it with LAPACK

Comment: Thanks for the further suggestions. I have checked, and none of the diagonals contain zeros (or anything close), and the matrix is diagonally dominant

Comment: Could you post your matrix?

Comment: Here is a file containing the matrix: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dxvhku1gcti5gg/A.txt?dl=0